# How to use a column created with ColumnTransformer pipeline in the same pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using the `ColumnTransformer` method of sklearn to build a pipeline for data processing. Inside the `ColumnTransformer` I am creating new columns for my dataset that are combinations of other columns, but in the next step I want to use this new column that were just created but I am getting the error that this column does not exist. I understand that it does not exist in the original dataset but why can't I use this new column? Or if I can: how?
The code is the following:

```
def sum_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["relatives"]  # feature names out

def sum_relatives(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']
    return X_copy

def cat_travel_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["relatives"]  # feature names out

def categorize_travel(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()

    conditions = [
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] == 0),
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 1) & (X_copy['total_relatives'] <= 3),
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 4)
    ]
    categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    X_copy['traveling_category'] = np.select(conditions, categories, default='Unknown')
    return X_copy

class_order = [[1, 2, 3]]

ord_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    OrdinalEncoder(categories=class_order)    
    )

def interval_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["interval"]  # feature names out

def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    median_age_by_class = X_copy.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].median().reset_index()
    median_age_by_class.columns = ['Pclass', 'median_age']
    for index, row in median_age_by_class.iterrows():
        class_value = row['Pclass']
        median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    return X_copy

def age_processor():
    return make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(age_transformer, feature_names_out=interval_name),
        )

total_relatives_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(sum_relatives, feature_names_out=sum_name)
)

travel_category_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(categorize_travel, feature_names_out=cat_travel_name)
)

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
    )

num_pipeline = make_pipeline(
        StandardScaler()
    )

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
        ("ord", ord_pipeline, ['Pclass']),
        ("age_processing", age_processor(), ['Pclass', 'Age']),
        ("total_relatives", total_relatives_pipeline, ['SibSp', 'Parch']),
        ("travel_category", travel_category_pipeline, ['total_relatives']),
        ("cat", cat_pipeline, ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'traveling_category', 'age_interval']),
        ("num", num_pipeline, ['Fare']),
    ])
```

This code gives the error that `total_relatives` is not a column of the dataset when I call the `fit_transform`method with:

```
data_processed = preprocessing.fit_transform(titanic_data)
```

Well, it is true, the `total_relatives` is indeed not a column of the original dataset, it is being created dynamically inside the `ColumnTransformer`. Do I need to create it again if I want to use the "travel_category" step? Can't I recover it from the previously step and use it?

the same thing will happen in the next step since `traveling_category` and `age_interval` were created in the previous steps and are not from the original dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mismatch between the columns that the function transformer returns, and its `feature_names_out=` name. They are clashing, both in terms of how many features are returned and their name. I firstly made sure that each function transformer only returns the one column (or more) that it's supposed to, and also changed the names to make them consistent. This way, the number of features and names defined in `feature_names_out=` matches the actual returned data for each transformer.

A second issue was that new features are created in the `ColumnTransformer`, and an attempt is made to access those variables by other parts of the same `ColumnTransformer`. This won't work as the column transformer runs things in parallel. What you'd need to do is chain the column transformers in a sequence, such that the next column transformer can access the new variables created from the earlier one. I have made this change to the code.

I made some other minor changes, including forcing transformers to return `pandas` dataframes rather than `numpy` arrays.

The new preprocessor:

[image]

Its output column names:

```py
Index(['Sex_female', 'Sex_male', 'Embarked_C', 'Embarked_Q', 'Embarked_S',
       'traveling_category_A', 'traveling_category_B', 'traveling_category_C',
       'age_interval_(0, 10]', 'age_interval_(10, 20]',
       'age_interval_(20, 30]', 'age_interval_(30, 40]',
       'age_interval_(40, 50]', 'age_interval_(50, 60]',
       'age_interval_(60, 70]', 'age_interval_(70, 100]', 'Pclass', 'Fare',
       'PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'],
      dtype='object')
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
titanic_data = pd.read_csv('../titanic.csv')

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

from sklearn import set_config
set_config(transform_output='pandas')

#
# Sum relatives
#
def sum_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["total_relatives"]  # feature names out

def sum_relatives(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']
    return X_copy[['total_relatives']]

total_relatives_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(sum_relatives, feature_names_out=sum_name)
)

#
#Categorize travel
#
def cat_travel_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["traveling_category"]  # feature names out

def categorize_travel(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()

    conditions = [
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] == 0),
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 1) & (X_copy['total_relatives'] <= 3),
        (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 4)
    ]
    categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    X_copy['traveling_category'] = np.select(conditions, categories, default='Unknown')
    return X_copy[['traveling_category']]

travel_category_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(categorize_travel, feature_names_out=cat_travel_name)
)

#
# Ordinal encoder
#
class_order = [[1, 2, 3]]

ord_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    OrdinalEncoder(categories=class_order)    
    )

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse_output=False)
    )

#Numerical for fare
fare_pipeline = make_pipeline(
        StandardScaler()
    )

#
# Age transformer
#
def interval_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["age_interval"]  # feature names out

def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    median_age_by_class = X_copy.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].median().reset_index()
    median_age_by_class.columns = ['Pclass', 'median_age']
    for index, row in median_age_by_class.iterrows():
        class_value = row['Pclass']
        median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = \
            X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    return X_copy[['age_interval']]

def age_processor():
    return make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(age_transformer, feature_names_out=interval_name),
        )

#
# Column transformers
#
preprocessing_initial = ColumnTransformer([
        ("ord", ord_pipeline, ['Pclass']),
        ("age_processing", age_processor(), ['Pclass', 'Age']),
        ("num", fare_pipeline, ['Fare']),
        ("total_relatives", total_relatives_pipeline, ['SibSp', 'Parch'])],
        remainder='passthrough',
        verbose_feature_names_out=False
)

preprocessing_travel_category = ColumnTransformer(
    [("travel_category", travel_category_pipeline, ['total_relatives'])],
    remainder='passthrough',
    verbose_feature_names_out=False
)

preprocessing_cat = ColumnTransformer(
    [("cat", cat_pipeline, ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'traveling_category', 'age_interval'])],
    remainder='passthrough',
    verbose_feature_names_out=False
)

#Final transformer
preprocessor = make_pipeline(
    preprocessing_initial,
    preprocessing_travel_category,
    preprocessing_cat
)

#Run
preprocessor.fit(titanic_data)
preprocessor.fit_transform(titanic_data).columns
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your time and the effort in making it clear to me. I learned a lot of things from your code and definitly it shed a light on where I was having trouble. I really apprecite it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure @Dimitri! Thanks for your kind comments. A few other details...`remainder='passthrough'` means each column transformer will keep the unused features rather than dropping them by default. The `verbose_feature_names_out=` option preserves your *own* feature names rather than the column transformer making them longer (it would add on the name of each step by default, so `age_interval` and `Fare` would become `age_processing__age_interval` and `num__Fare` for example). Happy to clarify anything further.

Comment: This `verbose_feature_names_out` is really handy. Knowing that before would save me a lot of trouble hehe thanks a lot.
I have one more question if you don't mind. In the end, if I want to drop some columns, can I build something like:

    `preprocessing_drop = ColumnTransformer(
        [("drop", drop_columns(), ['Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'])],
        remainder='passthrough',
        verbose_feature_names_out=False
    )`

or there is another more handy option to just drop those three columns?

Comment: No worries. Yeah the `verbose_...` flag can help a lot with keeping informative names. I think your approach would work. A simpler variation is to use the strings `"passthrough"`/`"drop"` in place of an estimator: `ColumnTransformer([('dropper', 'drop', ['Name', ...])], remainder='passthrough', verbose_...)`. You could also do it by defining a `FunctionTransformer` that drops columns, and chaining it onto the end of a pipeline: `dropper_transformer = FunctionTransformer(lambda df: df.drop(columns=['Name', ...])`, then `preprocessor = Pipeline([..., ('dropper', dropper_transformer)])`.

Comment: i managed to make it work. Thanks for the time and the various answers in that question and in the other question yesterday. Learned a lot. Have a nice weekend :))

Comment: Glad you got it working. My pleasure to have helped. Projects are a great way to learn. It can take some significant investment in time, effort, and figuring things out, but that's where a lot of the learning is in my experience. Have a nice weekend too.